Need help explaining why the area of a triangle remains constant regardless of the positions of two points

The points $A$ and $B$ representing two complex numbers, $w_1$ and $w_2$, move on a circle with center $I(1, 1)$ and radius $\sqrt{2},$ and $△IAB$ is a right triangle at $I$. Find the area of  $△MNI$, providing that $M$ represents the complex number $2w_1 + w_2 - 2 - 2i,$ and point $N$ represents the complex number $4w_2 - 2w_1 - 1 - i.$

In the solution, the author transitioned the origin to point $I,$ (which means now $I = (0;0)$) and let $A = (\sqrt{2}; 0)$ and $B = (0; \sqrt{2})$. He then found points $M$ and $N$ (on the new coordinate plane): $M = (2\sqrt{2}; \sqrt{2}),$ $N = (-2\sqrt{2}; 4\sqrt{2}).$ With the coordinates of all $3$ points, he then calculated the area using the formula $S = \dfrac{1}{2}|x_M \cdot y_N + x_N \cdot y_M|.$
This solution seems predicated on the idea that regardless of the positions of $A$ and $B,$ (as long as $△IAB$ is a right triangle as given), the area of $△MNI$ remains constant, so we could pick 'easy' values for $A$ and $B$ and proceed to find $M,$ $N,$ and the area. Is it something trivial to see? I struggle to understand why this is the case. Please advise.
Thank you!

I think the area is invariant only because the equations for $M$ and $N$ are linear combinations of $A, B, I$. I'd say it's not obvious enough to do without some explanation.

@aschepler maybe as the question doesn't specify anything about $\omega_{1,2}$, the author uses this to their advantage.

@aschepler After some scratch work, I believe that the area remains invariant in this particular case because $M$ and $N$ are chosen (by the problem statement) such that $\vec{IM}$ and $\vec{IN}$ are linear combinations of $\vec{IA}$ and $\vec{IB}$ and nothing else, which results in $IM$, $IN$, and $MN$ being constant. If the problem hadn't been 'nice' (e.g. $\vec{IM} = a\vec{IA} + b\vec{IB} + d\vec{IC}$ for some positive $d$ and fixed $C ≠ I,$ the area would have not been constant. Please let me know what you think!

Yes, I think that's the correct version of the idea in my first comment, which wasn't specific enough.

Going forward, such a posted question could really benefit with an image that illustrates the geometric problem.  For help managing an image, see the Images section, at the bottom of
this article
and see also this article.

Modifying answer as ten_to_tenth saw that answer could be in terms of linear combination.  I like that approach so here is a changed answer.
(The central idea of rotating a triangle around one of its points keeps the same area is still the key.)
$\left| z \right| = r$ and $z,a,b,k \in \mathbb{C}$ Then the triangle given by the three points, the first being the rotation center: 
{k}, {az +k  }, and {bz +k} 
will have the same area for any $z$ on the circle that is chosen. $z$ is a point on a circle around the origin of radius r.  If use a $z$ at a different angle around the circle,  then $az$ and $bz$ will be rotated the same amount.  Rotations for complex multiplication just add. Translating all the points of the triangle by the same vector, $k$, also does not change the area.
So now we just have to show we have that form.  Let $\left| z \right| = \sqrt{2}$ Then let us define 
$w_{1} = z+ 1 +i $ 
$w_{2} = z i+ 1 +i $ 
Then if we plug in we get three points 
{1+i }, { (2+i)z + 1+i } and {(-2+4i} z + 1+i} 
We have the form we want.  Picking any z on the circle will not change the magnitude.  It will change the directions the same amount,  so the triangle is just rotated around the $1+i$ point of triangle.
Note that this is special in that $k$ is the same for all three points so they are rotating around the same center.  Take z on a unit circle.  Then if we had a mapping such as 0, $z$, and $zi+1$,  the area changes when we use different $z$.  Take $z =i$, have an area of zero.  So the way the 1+i offsets were used problem was special so the $k$ came out exactly the same.

Thank you! I think you're right. However, after some scratch work, I believe that the area remains invariant in this particular case because $M$ and $N$ are chosen (by the problem statement) such that $\vec{IM}$ and $\vec{IN}$ are linear combinations of $\vec{IA}$ and $\vec{IB}$ and nothing else, which results in $IM$, $IN$, and $MN$ being constant. If the problem hadn't been 'nice' (e.g. $\vec{IM} = a\vec{IA} + b\vec{IB} + d\vec{IC}$ for some positive $d$ and fixed $C ≠ I,$ the area would have not been constant. Please let me know what you think!

Liked your comment about linear combination.  So I  redid answer using that from the start.  Hopefully nobody wanted old answer.

If $A = w_1$ and $B = w_2$, then we may take $w_1 = 1 + i + \sqrt{2} e^{i \theta}$ and $w_2 = 1 + i + \sqrt{2} e^{i \varphi}$ where $\theta, \varphi \in [0, 2\pi)$ and $|\theta - \varphi| = \pi/2$.  Then the author essentially claims there exists an isometry $f : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ that satisfies $f(1 + i) = 0$, $f(w_1) = \sqrt{2}$, and $f(w_2) = \sqrt{2}i$.  To find $f$ explicitly, we first perform the translation
$$g_1(z) = z - (1+i),$$
then followed by a suitable rotation
$$g_2(z) = z e^{-i\theta}$$
then followed by an optional reflection if $\varphi < \theta$:
$$g_3(z) = \bar z,$$
so $f$ is the composition of these transformations:
$$f(z) = \begin{cases} g_2(g_1(z)), & \theta > \varphi \\ g_3(g_2(g_1(z)), & \varphi < \theta. \end{cases}$$
It is for this reason that the vertices of $\triangle MNI$ can be taken to be a specific set of coordinates, because any $A, B$ satisfying the conditions of the problem can be suitably transformed (without changing areas, angles, or distances).  The author isn't picking specific values for $w_1$ and $w_2$ per se, but rather, proceeding from the idea that any particular choice can be translated, rotated, and possibly reflected so that the resulting figure preserves the desired area but is located on a coordinate plane that makes the calculation straightforward.

Thank you! Thb, I have not studied mapping and complex number representations that you were using, so I've been struggling to understand this answer. However, I'm looking to study college algebra soon so hopefully I will be able to revisit your answer and understand it then. Thank you very much for your help (on my other question also!)!
